# Do Technomancers need a commlink?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, technomancer

So I had never heard of Shadowrun before one of my players brought it up and asked if we could play it. I got the book, and have been perusing it for a few days.

One of my players says he wants to be a technomancer, so I've been reading up on that.

My question is: Does a technomancer need a commlink for his PAN, or does he naturally generate it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Technomancers do not need a commlink.

SR4 p.69:

> Technomancers are a new and unique character type in the Shadowrun
>   universe. Emerged characters are mysteriously able to interface with
>   the global Matrix via their "biological PAN' without resorting to
>   foreign hardware or devices.

SR4 p.93:

> Technomancers can access and manipulate the Matrix through their own
>   sheer force of will.

SR4 p.239:

> The neural pathways and brain chemistry of technomancers are such that
>   they can send, receive, and interpret wireless signals, giving them
>   instant access to the wireless Matrix, no electronics or cyberware
>   required.

SR4 p.239:

> Technomancers have their own version of the persona, known as the
>   living persona. It is essentially an organic commlink and sim module
>   in the technomancer's head.

Comment: Although if they decide to buy a real commlink it's not as bad to get hacked.

Comment: @CatLord Absolutely.

Comment: Alright thanks. Thats all I wanted. You are great.

Comment: Alright, seconday question. Does he need image link on contacts to be able to see the status of his ammo, fuel, etc?

Comment: Re-word please?  I assume you mean eye contacts in which case, as long as they function he can tap into it.

Comment: I want to know if he has access to his digital ammo counter info from his gun in his mind? Or does he need his Eye Contacts to physically see the information?

Comment: You might want to open a new question, as it is quite a complex thing, and there are different interpretations. But basically, they can be assumed to have an Image Link and to have access to all their peripheral devices without any additional equipment, except smartlink which requires some gear or a special complex form.

Comment: I feel compelled to note that this "brain detects radio waves" thing was rather loudly protested when it first came out as _making no sense physically_.  My conclusion, since they stuck with it, is that this is an unqualifiedly magical ability, since it's biologically essentially impossible.

Comment: @Ichoran Well, since assensing can pick up Technomancer ability, there's definitely some support for that notion.

Comment: @GMJoe - Agreed, though you can pick up various other things (presence of cyberware, for instance) that are not overtly magical.  It adds to the "technomancy is magical" evidence, however.

Answer (score 6):

Actually technomancer DO need a commlink, because their brain is not a suitable place to store data, and whenever a security guard / drone controls his identify, he must broadcast his SIN.

Also, technomancer's biological PAN always operates in hidden mode, which is forbidden in some places and just socially frown upon in most other places. So having a commlink, even a shitty one, helps.

More info on that in the Unwired add on.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.StackExchange.com!  Please take a look at the [About] when you get a chance.